# MYSQL SELECT WHERE с несколькими значениями

Tags: mysqli, массивы, php, select, mysql

Нужно, чтобы в id учитывалось несколько значений. Что-то типа такого:

```
$array=(5,1,8,6);
$string=implode(','$array);
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$string'");
```

Comment: Правильнее $string=implode(',',$array);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE id IN ($string)`

Comment: @Fike, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: @Expert, это был комментарий, который кто-то вытянул в ответы.